# Should we merge [static-member] to [static-members]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, synonym-request

They seem to be the same tag.

[static-member](/questions/tagged/static-member) is used in 9 questions; [static-members](/questions/tagged/static-members) is used in 355 questions.

Comment: [static-member] is not used at all. What are you talking about? .... Nah, cleaned the 9 questions up and changed the tag to [static-members] where appropriate. The tag should disappear automatically now no questions are tagged with it.